# word for compliance/integrity

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm trying to remember a word from a company name, it's about integrity/stringency/risk assessment and making sure that activities comply with regulations and health and safety.

The company does risk management for events but I can't remember what the company name is - it includes this word.

Comment: Trying to find a company name may be off topic on this site.

Comment: I work in financial _governance_.